# How to create the required certificates for iOS Development?

Tags: iphone

I have registered for the Apple Developer Program and I am now able to login into the portal. I am a very newbie to App development for iPhone, however, I have read a few tutorials and blogs.

My question is how can I generate the certificate for my iPod Touch 4.3 viOS device. I could not find any easy to follow links, so came here to know the steps from someone experienced and someone who has already done similar task.

Also, I have installed iphone sdk on my machine. I tried to create a Hello World example. But when I do 'Build & Go' it gives some error about sdk... like no sdk found.

Can somebody help me with a easy to follow steps / links for creating the certificates and hopefully how to set up the iOS Development environment on my Mac.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a pretty good tutorial on deploying iphone apps to your device.
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices
It shows you how to create certificates, etc. with pictures and all.

As for your SDK error, go to Project>Edit Project Settings and under Architectures, change the Base SDK to one of the listed versions.

Good luck with your developing!