# "Valid signing identity not found" Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode

I bought a new Mac, and installed Xcode again etc.
But I have problems with certificates and provisioning profiles.
In Organizer, Xcode is giving the error under the status of all my provisioning profiles:
"Valid signing identity not found"
Is it because I bought a new Mac?
I searched on the web a lot, but I couldn't find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

1)

do you have an older Macintosh that you used to build your iOS / MacOS apps on?

If so, you need to migrate your certificates and provisioning profiles.

[This tutorial shows you how to do that](http://christophersu.net/2012/migrating-ios-certificates-profiles/).

2)

If you never built iOS or Mac apps before, then you need to create new certificates and provisioning profiles.

[This related question should point you the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886090/how-to-create-the-required-certificates-for-ios-development).

Comment: I had an older iMac where I developed on. But I already fixed it, I made new certificates etc. Thanks!